# Apache CXF 3. Include files in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, apache

I am using ***Apache CXF 3*** .. 
I generated the JavaScript files for your service Java JAX-Sun utility wsdl2js ... But in the generated class files used `CxfApacheOrgClient ()` ... What do I attach a file to the class became visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires download "Apach CXF framework 3". **The required file is located inside the archive** (\ apache-cxf-3.0.1 **\ etc \ cxf-utils.js**)